# GitHub Atom feeds for new releases or commits don't work in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, github

GitHub provides [Atom Feeds](https://help.github.com/articles/news-feed/) for various kinds of things like commits, releases, pull requests, etc. For a chat-room that is specifically dedicated to software, like our chat-room for the [Mathematica Plugin for IntelliJ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8636/intellijidea-plugin-for-mathematica), it would be extremely helpful if we could use those feeds to announce new releases.

Unfortunately, it does not work currently. If I'm using for instance

https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin/releases.atom

as feed in the chat-room, new releases don't appear. I [talked to C.E.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33748283#33748283) in chat who has some experience with this:

> SE is very picky about details. First of all, if your RSS doesn't validate then it won't read it, even though other RSS readers read it. But this is not the case here because your feed validates. Secondly, and this is the reason why the feed didn't work for over a month this summer IIRC, I believe that it uses the "guid" field.
>
> As I remember it I changed the guid field, it stopped working, and then I changed it back to what it was before and it started working again. This could be a problem because your feed doesn't have a guid field. SE might use it I think to distinguish between which posts are new and which aren't when it loads the RSS feed.

In the meantime, C.E. provided me with a [working feed link](http://packagedata.net/index.php/feed/intellij_releases) as a quick fix.

**Question:** Can this be fixed so that Atom feeds from GitHub work out of the box?

Comment: I can confirm that this indeed does not work for me either, and there unfortunately does not seem to be any word from the Stack Exchange team.